# Can we introduce the mathjax plug-in to the french stack exchange?

Tags: feature-request, markdown

More than [40 different](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216606/610179) stack exchange forumns allow people to write MathJax in their markdown

Can we allow the MathJax plugin on the  french stack exchange?

I would to color code words from languages outside of French such as Russian, English, Spanish, Español, Deutch German, et cetra.

Also, we could use very small amounts of mathjax to ask what the french word for some mathematical symbol is.

```
¿Quel mot pour phrase les mathématiciens français utilisent-ils pour $\color{teal}{\text{sets}}$? utilisent-ils pour des collections, des ensembles de nombres ou des conteneurs de nombres?   

\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\} \cap \{4, 5, 6, 7\} = \{4, 5\}
    

$\{1, 2, 3\} \cup \{3, 4, 5\} = \{1, 2, 3, 4 , 5\}$   

Les mathématiciens américains utilisent le mot $\color{teal}{\text{set}}$
```

[image: a screen capture taken from the math stack exchange]

quel est le mot français pour le symbole de la tasse utilisé pour prendre l'union de deux ensembles de nombres ?